# Adapting/cropping an animated svg, depending on aspect ratio

Tags: svg, layout, orientation, gsap

I don't find a way to make a proper crop of my svg image.
[image: example]

First, i am a newbie.

I tried fiddling in css with position absolute/relative, but the fact that this svg is animated with gsap makes me unable to load the svg as a background image in css.

I also tried modifying the viewbox parameters, but it seem a bit complex as a solution. I wonder if that can be responsive.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="nav-bar>
      "a nav bar here"
   </div>

   <div class="animatedSvg">
      <svg>
        the long svg code here of my fancy animated gsap.
      </svg>
   </div>
</div>

Css: elements are using flexbox for placement and sizing.
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100
}
.nav-bar{
display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.animatedSvg{
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 0%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

I am starting to wonder if this can only be fixed by controlling the viewBox with some javascript?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am trying to do like in this picture:
https://imgur.com/57qxpkp

And the problem is that it is quite strange to make the svg do this while being responsive.

i am now exploring this page to try to figure things out: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the answer was in fiddling with height, width, and the inline svg option preserveAspectRatio!

With these in the inline svg's code, things are now working as they should :)

```
`height="100%"
width="auto"
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"`
```